# Is it possible to reference C enums from an assembly file?

Tags: c, enums, nasm, header-files

syscalls.h

```
enum Syscall {
  OPEN_FILE,
  READ_FILE,
  CLOSE_FILE
};
```

syscalls.s

```
extern WRITE_TO_SCREEN
global write_to_screen
write_to_screen:
  mov eax, WRITE_TO_SCREEN
  mov ebx, [esp+4]
  int 0x80
  ret
```

Gives me this error:

```
stdlib/syscalls.o: In function `write_to_screen':
stdlib/syscalls.s:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `WRITE_TO_SCREEN'
make: *** [kernel.elf] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't.
You could do something like:

#### enum_support.h

```
#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__
#define ENUM_START
#define ENUM_VALUE(key,value) .equ key,value
#define ENUM_END(typename)
#else
#define ENUM_START typedef enum{
#define ENUM_VALUE(key,value) key=value,
#define ENUM_END(typename)} typename;
#endif
```

#### syscalls.h

```
#include "enum_support.h"

ENUM_START
ENUM_VALUE(OPEN_FILE,0)
ENUM_VALUE(READ_FILE,1)
ENUM_VALUE(CLOSE_FILE,2)
ENUM_END(Syscall)
```

And then have `test.c` and `test.s` include `syscalls.h`

`gcc -c test.c`
`gcc -c test.s`

Not sure it's very helpful, but I don't know any other way to share enums (which are non existent in assembly).
You could do `cpp test.c` or `cpp -D__ASSEMBLER__ test.s` to see the emitted code.